# How to distinguish access from Cordova/PhoneGap or others (standard browsers in smartphones)

Tags: android, cordova

I want to distinguish access from Cordova/PhoneGap or others in a web server.

I tried to see HTTP_USER_AGENT sent from a cordova app. But there is nothing particularly distinctive about the standard browser (webView).

This is what the Cordova app sent to the server:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.2; ja-jp; Galaxy Nexus Build/ICL53F) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30`

Do you know how to distinguish these in an easier way?

Comment: Why not add a query string parameter to the URL you are loading through the PhoneGap app?

Comment: I wanna distinguish cordova in several pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap uses the [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) at its core. So all the HTTP requests from your PhoneGap app will be placed through the `WebView`. That explains why you don't see any difference in User-Agent string.

If it is your own app, you can

- modify the PhoneGap sources to include additional headers using the [`loadUrl (String url, Map<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29) method
- or, as @codemonkey suggested in the comment above, include a string parameter in all your requests.